# Nuxt Socket.io is unresponsive without any error

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt-socket-io along with an Express.js server with socketio as well.
When I start up the client/server, the server-side socket.io connects and console for the server will print "connected").

When I try to connect with nuxt (the client-side part of socket.io), nothing happens. Mounted() is called correctly (the "hm" console log prints out), but the socket never seems to be made. I tried testing `this.socket.on('connect-error')` and `this.socket.on('connect-timeout')` for the CLIENT side (the server-side socket.io connects properly), but nothing was ever emitted after about 5 minutes of waiting. The `persist: true` isn't the issue either; I tried to remove it and had the same issue. I initially didn't have `this.socket.open()` and had the same problems, so I don't think that line does anything, either.

NuxtJS frontend

```js
mounted() {
    console.log("hm");
    this.socket = this.$nuxtSocket({
      channel: '/profile',
      persist: true
    })
    this.socket.open();

    this.socket.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log("connected")
    })

    //Listens for the SERVER-EMITTED event 'send'
    this.socket.on('send', (message) => {
      console.log("client received event!")
      console.log(message);
    });

  },
  methods: {
    sendMessage() {
      // This method IS CALLED correctly with a button (I checked), but the emit is not transmitting
      // sends a CLIENT-EMITTED event to the server
      this.socket.emit('send-message', {
        message: "hey!"
      }, (res) => {console.log(res)})
    },
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
  io: {
    sockets: [{
      name: 'main',
      default: true,
      url: 'http://localhost:3000'
    }]
  },
```

My Express Backend (port is 8080)

```js
import express from "express";
import { db } from "./app/config/db.config";
import { authRouter } from "./app/routes/auth.router";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

// run on connection to socket
io.on('connection', (socket: any) => {
  console.log("connected")
})

// listens for the CLIENT-EMITTED event 'send-message'
io.on('send-message', (message: any) => {
  console.log(message + "server received!");
  // sends a SERVER-EMITTED event "send" to be received by nuxt client
  io.emit('send', "message!")
  
})

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

Axios is also running on port 8080, I don't know if that would cause any issues but I don't get any errors when I try to run my whole program (which includes login/registration with axios).
Anyone know why my events aren't transmitting? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your server code, you're adding your `'send-message'` event listener to the `io` object, which is your main socket.io Server instance. However, event listeners should be added to the `socket` object you get from the `connection` event. Something like:

```
// A new connection comes in
io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
  // Now we listen for the event that comes from this particular socket
  socket.on('send-message', (message: any) => {
    // You also use the Socket instance to send events back to clients, not to the `io` Server.
    socket.emit('send', "message!");
  });
});
```

[The Socket instance docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-socket-instance/) have more info on what you can do with these sockets.